# Is it possible to see how many times a particular tag badge has been awarded?

Tags: discussion, badges

I'm curious because [the main badges have a count associated with them](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges) (i.e., *"altruist, 177 awarded"*), but it's not apparent that you can find out how the number of times a tag badge has been awarded.

I've been active in the [*acoustics* tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustics?sort=unanswered) for rather a long time (and will keep chipping away at the bronze!) but it occurs to me that there are some tags that are a bit more esoteric. Obviously that means there are just fewer questions asked. But it also seems that they are less likely to be upvoted either due to unfamiliarity or disinterest within the community. (Hopefully this isn't too volatile to ask about, I'm simply curious.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze

You can reach it through the menus by:

- Go to your user page.
- Click on "badges" in the horizontal menu.
- Select any badge you have earned.
- Click on "Badges" in the box in the upper right.

For the non-tag badges, it will then tell you how many of each one has been awarded on the site.  To get the tag badge numbers, you need one more step:

- Click on the "Bronze Badge," "Silver Badge," or "Gold Badge" under the "Tag Badges" section.